# 애인, 소중한 사람 - what is the difference?

Tags: word-choice

I read from dictionary that 애인 means lover. Can I say my husband/wife is my 애인,too? 
As for 소중한 사람, does it mean lover too? Or is it more like a "beloved person",including family? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You could, however, we usually don't call husband and wife to "애인". We use 남편 and 아내 respectively. 소중한사람 could be your family member, your best friend, and anyone that you think an important person in your life literally.

Answer (score 2):

Calling your spouse your 애인 would sound rather weird, and I wouldn't recommend it.  When we refer to a married person having an 애인, usually that means they're having an extramarital affair.

소중한 사람 literally means "a person who is dear [to me]."  It could be anyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your husband/wife 애인. **애 means love. 인 means human**. So if you love someone, you call him 애인.

소중한 사람 means a person who is really important in your life. It can be your family, friends or lover.

Aww. I have to add more explanation because there is conflict to the other answers.

애인 is normally used for **the person whom you love but you don't get married**. So after your marriage, there is a room for misunderstanding. Like this,

> You: (Introducing your wife) 이 사람이 내 애인이야.
>   Your friend: You already get married but do you have 애인? You are cheating on your 아내 with the 애인

That's why they don't recommend use 애인 for husband/wife, I suppose.

But if you ask 'Can I say my husband/wife is my 애인?', in my opinion, you can say. If there is someone who misunderstand like above situation, you can add explanation "I used 애인 as a literal meaning. I used 애인 as a meaning of lover." Like this,

> You: (Introducing your wife) 이 사람이 내 애인이야.
>   Your friend: You already get married but do you have 애인? You are cheating on your 아내 with the 애인 
>   You: 아니 그런 의미의 애인이 아니라, 사랑하는 사람이라는 뜻의 애인이라고.

I think actually it can be more romantic. Anyways **it's true that the above paragraph concept is much more general and common. And this paragraph concept is not usual but I think it's possible.**

All in all, we normally don't call husband/wife to "애인". However, in my opinion, we can use 애인 for husband/wife.